# Should interviews be arranged by less-preferred schools first?

Tags: faculty-application, interview

I read that some candidates will arrange their interviews by not placing the preferred ones at the beginning. How that is possible? Do they wait for few weeks to know all their interviews and then decide?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a luxurious problem that not many people will have.  Getting both a lot of interviews in short order *and* being able to steer in which order they happen seems a bit like magical Christmas land to me (all campus interviews I had so far were more or less "come on this day" - I could reschedule one because I was at the time at a conference, but the communication never sounded like "pick a date" to me).

Comment: I read it from two sites, the guys graduated from top schools.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea since it might make it more likely to get the less desirable offer first.

Comment: @StrongBad this really depends on the schedules and how quickly you have to reply. Sometimes it is doable.

Comment: @StrongBad That would be exactly the point: get the less desirable offer first, so that when you get an offer from the stronger program you are in an ideal negotiating position. Not to say it would work out, but that would be the rationale.

Comment: @Tim it doesn't matter what order the offers come in terms of negotiating, it is simply a matter of how close together they come.

Comment: @StrongBad actually, it will matter what order the offers come in if the offer periods don't have substantial overlap.  Since it's not uncommon these days to have an offer with a very short time limit (reportedly as short as 2 days in some cases!) arranging for this overlap may not be practical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common strategy, but it can backfire on you in the following way.

If you interview for the position that least interests you and are given a job offer, you may have to respond to that offer before you have a chance to complete the other interviews (or before those institutions are ready to make an offer.)  If this happens you may be faced with the choice of accepting an offer from your least favorite institution or refusing that offer and then running the risk that none of the other interviews will result in an offer.

Answer (score 4):

As I have heard of the practice, it is essentially putting the less-favored opportunity first so that the person will be more practiced and more ready to deal with questions and challenges when they go to their more favored opportunity.  I'm not sure whether this is actually a good idea, but if one wants to do it, it is really only possible if the invitations happen to come closely enough together that the person knows about both invitations while scheduling is still being sorted out.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the tactic is to try to schedule interviews in places you really want as late as possible and try to schedule interviews in less desirable places as early as possible. Depending on the schedules, sometimes this is feasible. For example, some times people pack 5 or even 10 interviews in just a few weeks. Of course you have to make sure you are not too exhausted when you get to the important interviews.

I have heard many people recommending this strategy, and I somewhat recommend it myself, although it is not really a big deal. The idea is that regardless of how much you prepare, you still learn a lot from your first interview and can significantly improve in the next ones (especially in aspects that are more difficult to prepare for, like the chalk talk). It is also about reducing stress - in the first interview many people are very stressed but once they see that they went through it and it is not so bad, they are more relaxed for their next interviews.